# A method in a class of JAX-WS project missing when called by client

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws, soap-client

I have a Java web service called "Customer_Service" which utilizes a class called "Customer" as a type. You can add a "Customer" object to a database using the "Customer_Service". In the client end I am unable to call a certain method in "Customer". All the other methods work fine except for this method. Below is how my Customer class looks.

```
public class Customer {

private int customerId;
private String dob;

public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
 }

public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
 }

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
 }

// this method cannot be accessed by client
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running the application with outdated classes. Try doing a full clean and build and see what happens. If it doesn't work my advice is to recreate the entire project. This will recreate any broken connections.

Comment: Clean and build did it. Thanks!